# split on regex python between two strings but inclusive using re.split and return a list

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split a piece of text in a file formatted like this:

```
module 
some text
endmodule

module 
some other text
endmodule
```

between the words module and endmodule and still include module and endmodule in the output string.

This is not a duplicate of other regex questions because I am trying to use re.split() to return a list, not find.

This is the regex I've tried

```
s=file.read()
l=re.split("module(.*)endmodule",s)
```

but it won't split anything...

Ideally final output would be a list that includes both modules as strings,

['module\n sometext\n endmodule', 'module\n someothertext\n endmodule']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you might want to design an expression similar to:

```
module(.*?)endmodule
```

not sure though.

#### Test with re.finditer

```
import re

regex = r"module(.*?)endmodule"

test_str = ("module \n"
    "some text\n"
    "endmodule\n\n"
    "module \n"
    "some other text\n"
    "endmodule")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.DOTALL)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

#### Test with `re.findall`

```
import re

regex = r"module(.*?)endmodule"

test_str = ("module \n"
    "some text\n"
    "endmodule\n\n"
    "module \n"
    "some other text\n"
    "endmodule")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.DOTALL))
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/iFxEMx/1/), if you wish to explore further or simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/iFxEMx/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

Comment: this is matching the entire file, but I have multiple occurences of this pattern in the file.

Comment: Sorry, your answer was perfect, I messed up. I need to include re.DOTALL

Answer (score 1):

We could use a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead as in

```
print(re.split('(?<=endmodule)[.\n]*?(?=module)', s))
```

giving

```
['module\nsome text\nendmodule', 'module\nsome other text\nendmodule']
```

where

```
s = ("module\n"
     "some text\n"
     "endmodule\n\n"
     "module\n"
     "some other text\n"
     "endmodule")
```